# mat2gray with structure fields

Tags: matlab, image-processing, structure

I'm trying to display a matrix as an image with `mat2gray` and `imshow`. The data is saved as part of a structure. When I call the field separately I can display the image fine, but if I try to do it inside of a `for` loop it doesn't work. Does any one have an idea why this might be happening?

Example:

```
imshow(mat2gray(MyVals(5).Data))
```

Result: Success!

```
for L=1:numel(MyVals)
    imshow(mat2gray(MyVals(L).Data))
end
```

Result:

> Attempted to access limits(2); index out of bounds because
>   numel(limits)=0.
>
> Error in mat2gray (line 38) if limits(2)==limits(1)   % Constant Image

Comment: Please post the error. Why does it fail? Essentially it is the same statement, if you put `L=5`.

Comment: This is the error message:
Attempted to access limits(2); index out of bounds because numel(limits)=0.
Error in mat2gray (line 38)
if limits(2)==limits(1)   % Constant Image// I know it's not a Constant Image, because I can display the image without the for loop//Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: see if `MyVals(5).data` and `MyVals(L).data` have the same format, where L is the value when you encounter the error.

Comment: Presetting the range of L works!! (for L = 1:100, instead of 1:numel(MyVals)). Thank You for your help!! But I have a second question. I get the same error message if I do not display the images immediately within the for loop. Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Two questions: 1. At what value of `L` you receive the error, if you do not preset the range for `L`  2. Paste the contents of `MyVals(5).data` and `MyVals(L).Data` for a value where `L` is the value when you get error.

Comment: Yes! Thank You so much for these tips and the help @Parag! It turns out thelast 2 matrices are empty data sets, hence the error.